# ColdFusion 11 crash

Tags: coldfusion

I was messing around with the class path in my CF11 admin due to a project that I am working on and I managed to crash the server to the point where the only thing that I get is a nice blue screen with a 500 error. I've checked the logs and I will paste what I can on the bottom of the post but my hope is that someone will enlighten me so I won't have to re-install CF because I am on an amazon AMI instance and I don't even know if I can do that (haven't checked yet).

```
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,""
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The XML-RPC service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Metrics service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The ClientScope service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Runtime service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Solr service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The MailSpool service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The DataSource service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Debugging service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Security service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,""
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The DotNet service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The WatchService service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Monitoring service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","12/12/14","13:12:22",,"The Runtime service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
```

This is my jvm file

```
#
# VM configuration
#
# Where to find JVM, if {java.home}/jre exists then that JVM is used
# if not then it must be the path to the JRE itself

java.home=C:\\ColdFusion11\\jre

#
# If no java.home is specified a VM is located by looking in these places in this
# order:
#
#  1) ../runtime/jre
#  2) registry (windows only)
#  3) JAVA_HOME env var plus jre (ie $JAVA_HOME/jre)
#  4) java.exe in path
#

# Arguments to VM
java.args=-server  -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog -Duser.language=en -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random -Dcoldfusion.classPath={application.home}/lib/updates,{application.home}/lib,{application.home}/lib/axis2,{application.home}/gateway/lib/,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars,C:\\ColdFusion11\\jre\\lib

# Comma separated list of shared library path
java.library.path={application.home}/lib,{application.home}/jintegra/bin,{application.home}/jintegra/bin/international,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes/win

# Comma separated list of shared library path for non-windows
java.nixlibrary.path={application.home}/lib

java.class.path={application.home}/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes
```

Comment: I can't remember where that setting is stored, and can't be bothered looking, but if you just check for the most recently updated file in your ColdFusion dir, it's most likely gonna be stored in there. If you dig it out, I'll compare it to mine and let you know what the default value is.

Comment: (it might just be your jvm.config file. Mine's @ C:\apps\adobe\ColdFusion\11\express\cfusion\bin\jvm.config, and it was touched when I updated my ColdFusion Class Path setting in CFAdmin)

Comment: Side note, in future you are better off modifying the `jvm.config` file manually IMO. Though **always make a backup first**. Then you can restore it, as Adam described, if anything goes wrong. As you have seen, it is a key file. Any errors can prevent the CF server from starting entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you were editing the classpath via the CF administrator?  If so, look for the jvm.config file Adam mentioned and restore it from a backup, or another stock install.

You didn't appear to mention the type of ColdFusion install, or the operating system of your AMI instance.  My standalone ColdFusion 11 install on Windows 7 has the jvm.config here:

> C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\bin\jvm.config

And the contents are as follows.  **Do not** simply copy it wholesale as you might not have the exact same paths or memory settings as I do.  You can however use it as a point of reference for comparison.  Sorry, I would have just put this as a comment, but the file was too big for that.

```
#
# VM configuration
#
# Where to find JVM, if {java.home}/jre exists then that JVM is used
# if not then it must be the path to the JRE itself

java.home=C:\\ColdFusion11\\jre

#
# If no java.home is specified a VM is located by looking in these places in this
# order:
#
#  1) ../runtime/jre
#  2) registry (windows only)
#  3) JAVA_HOME env var plus jre (ie $JAVA_HOME/jre)
#  4) java.exe in path
#

# Arguments to VM

java.args=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Djava.security.policy={application.home}/lib/coldfusion.policy -Djava.security.auth.policy={application.home}/lib/neo_jaas.policy  -Dcoldfusion.classPath={application.home}/lib/updates,{application.home}/lib,{application.home}/lib/axis2,{application.home}/gateway/lib/,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random

# Comma separated list of shared library path

java.library.path={application.home}/lib,{application.home}/jintegra/bin,{application.home}/jintegra/bin/international,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes/win

# Comma separated list of shared library path for non-windows

java.nixlibrary.path={application.home}/lib

java.class.path={application.home}/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes
```

Comment: I am using CF 11 on Windows Server 2012 sorry about that

Comment: Good to hear.  I would recommend doing a text compare to make sure you get any settings back you needed.  Namely, your -Xmx was set to 1024m.  You also had several other JVM options such as Xdebug, Xrunjdwp, Djava.awt.headless, etc set that I didn't.